# Zend Lucene Lexicographical Range Search Returning Non-Relevant Results

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

I am using Zend Lucene to build a search feature for my website. All well and good.

Understanding that Lucene does searches lexicographically (e.g.
1,
110,
1111444,
2,
3,
4,
499238492834798,
5,
etc)

I have padded my numbers to 3 digits (ranging from 010 to 990).

When I do a range search for values 110 to 160 (e.g. fieldname:[110 TO 160])it is returning results for 040! Logically this is wrong as all the numbers would start with a 1 (although it would still search for 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 and 16) so it **should not** match this result!

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it from doing so?

[edit]
I misread the Zend Documentation. The Range Query that sorts results lexicographically. But my problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to find out why this is acting like this, so I'm doing a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i + 10)
{
 $queryString .= 'fieldname:' . ($term + $i) . ' ';
}
```

creates a query such as:

```
fieldname:110 fieldname:120 fieldname:130 fieldname:140 fieldname:150 fieldname:160
```

which does return the results I want exactly.